# Value of property Subscription must be a list of objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Using aws cloud formation designer to make a simple SNS topic with subscription and queue for SES. I connected the components but my stack fails to create the subscription.

Error: Value of property Subscription must be a list of objects

```
   "Resources": {
    "SNST3F2X9": {
        "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",
        "Properties": {
            "DisplayName": "EmailBounceTopic",
            "Subscription": [
                "EmailBounceSubscription"
            ],
            "TopicName": "EmailBounceTopic"
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "094fd7f3-2e35-4219-8f87-07ad335f85bb"
            }
        }
    },
    "SNST3FDSS": {
        "Type": "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
        "Properties": {
            "EndPoint": "BounceQueue",
            "Protocol": "SQS",
            "RawMessageDelivery": true,
            "TopicArn": {
                "Ref": "SNST3F2X9"
            }
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "b9524cd1-7d7a-46a6-9c34-33ceccccf3d4"
            }
        }
    },
    "SQSQ3OZGY": {
        "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
        "Properties": {
            "QueueName": "BounceQueue"
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "d5a6cfd6-4b52-486a-97c1-4021528c32fc"
            }
        },
        "DependsOn": [
            "SNST3FDSS"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `Subscription` is:

```
            "Subscription": [
                "EmailBounceSubscription"
            ]
```

But [Subscription](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-subscription.html) should be a list of objects in the form of (example):

```
    "Subscription" : [{
      "Endpoint" : "EmailBounceSubscription",
      "Protocol" : "email"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, and it did get farther. The designer didn't let me create drag and drop in a nested manner. I created a completely separate subscription and linked them in the designer.  Now throwing an error of "Invalid parameter: Email address (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; ". Endpoint shouldn't require a email if I want it to go to a queue right?

Comment: @haju I'm not sure what you want to do. I though want to use email address as the name `EmailBounceSubscription` suggetests. If you want to have SQS queue, you have to modify `Protocol` and `Endpoint`.

Comment: Sorry should of put that in the description. Trying to create a sns topic / subscription / simple queue to handle bounce emails. The subscription routes the bounce emails to a queue. I'll update description of my problem. I see what you mean now. Endpoint in the subscription should be my queue, and protocol sqs.